# Consuming API not working, what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

Not sure if this is the place to change things, but I have changed some things due to your comments, I stil cant see the pictures, but here is an update of the code:

JS app:

```
    import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    name: 'home',
    components: {
        ImageCard
    },
    data() {
        return {
            images: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchImages = () => {
            axios
                .get("https://foodish-api.herokuapp.com/api/images/pizza")
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.setState({ images: res.data.message });
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            this.images = fetchImages()
            });
        }
```

Index.cshtml code here:

```
<div id="app">
<div class="home">
    <li v-for="image in images" :key="image.id">
        <img :src="image.url" :alt="image.alt" />
    </li>
    
</div>
```

Obviously something wrong here but i cant seem to get it right since I cant see the pictures, what is still wrong here? Also, when your refer to something I should do different, please just point me in the right direction of the code :D

Comment: your fetchImages() return a `Promise` you need to use `then` and `this.images.push(WHAT_YOU_SHOULD_ADD)`  something like : `axios.get('http://webcode.me').then(resp => {  console.log(resp.data); });`

Comment: also image is an object, shouldn't be {{image.WHAT_EVER_PROPERTY}} ?

Comment: Have you added the vue scripts in your layout also

Comment: Yes I have added Vue, tried some mock data just to see that it works! Thx though! Now im trying another thing and there is still something im doing wrong, can I post code in comments? Have been trying but it will only send in plain text ://

Answer (score 1):

you did wrong the following:

1. create a method `fetchImages` and never call it.
2. `this.setState` this undifined function.
3. `this.images = fetchImages()` will lead you to infinite loop because this is a recursion function
4. in your `html` use `:src="image.url"` to show the image but you get  the data as string not object and you must use `:src="image"`

you can check the solution in this codesandbox project

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-ellis-rcifm?file=/src/App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <li v-for="image in images" :key="image.id">
      <img :src="image" :alt="image.alt" />
    </li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      images: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("https://foodish-api.herokuapp.com/api/images/pizza")
      .then((res) => {
        this.images = res.data;
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thx bro! Awesome tips, at least I think im decent in c# but I suck at Js and axios and what knox, Im watching the solution and I dont know if im retarded or what, but I cant get it to work... Jesus christ why am i even doing this.. This guy has a Vue.app, should I put that code in to my app.js?

Comment: something went wrong in codeandbox project and didn't save my modifications, I rewrite the code and put it in the answer, please check it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,when you call `fetchImages()`,you need to set `this.images=fetchImages()`,so that the data of `images` will be set.And if you want to display pictures,you can do like this:

```
<li v-for="image in images" :key="image.id">
     <img :src="image.url" :alt="image.alt"/>
</li>
```